# Git: misleading error: “remote repository not found” while I don’t have write access

Tags: git, github

Request your expert suggestions here. I am able to successfully do a git checkout and git pull.

However while pushing some changes to the remote, I encountered “remote respository not found”.

I tried to troubleshoot and realized that my write access is not approved/enabled yet.

Just wondering why cannot I just get an error message saying like  “access denied” while doing push rather that “remote repository not found”?

Can anybody suggest or advise here if there is a relevance of “remote repository not found” for not having write access while doing git push.

Comment: There is nothing you can do for that. the reason behind this is that there is no local feature in git for merging restrictions. this is a feature by Github (or other git hosts) that added to their software platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub uses "Not Found" where it means "Forbidden" in some circumstances to prevent inadvertently reveling the existence of a private repository.

> Requests that require authentication will return 404 Not Found,
>   instead of 403 Forbidden, in some places. This is to prevent the
>   accidental leakage of private repositories to unauthorized users.

[--GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

It is a common practice around the web.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that Github intentionally returns 404 (Not Found) vs 403 (Forbideden) in most places. This is to make sure it does not disclose that repo in fact exists to an unauthorized party.

One can argue that this might be safe to disclose this fact to an authenticated person that has read access to the repo, but at the moment they don't handle that case in a special way.

Comment: Thank you this explains